# does anyone know this bug?

Tags: bathroom, pest

I found these bugs in my bathroom in New York City. I can't find them on pest control websites. They don't look like roaches. Any ideas of what they are and how to get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the post to indicate where you live. Different types of insect live in different geographic locations.

Comment: Is that thing 0.2 meters long or 0.2 mm long? Some indication of size would be useful in identifying it.

Comment: some sort of waterbug? looks similar to something i had in NY

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because entomology isn't home improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Found it. It's a [brown-banded cockroach](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/URBAN/roaches/brown-banded_cockroach.htm)

[image]

> The life stages of the brown-banded cockroach, Supella longipalpa
>   Fabricius, showing an ootheca (first row), five instars of nymphs
>   (second row and first individual in third row) and both sexes of
>   adults (third row). Photograph by Lyle J. Buss, University of Florida.

Comment: Yuck.  I'm glad I didn't know about these.  Where do you live?